# How do I run a liquibase migration in my Spring Boot project with Gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, gradle, liquibase

So, I am currently building a project using Java Spring Boot v3.2.0 and Gradle v8.5.

I want to use Liquibase for my migrations, but whenever I try running any of the Liquibase tasks, it says
`Liquibase-core was not found  not found in the liquibaseRuntime configuration!`

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.2.0'
}

group = 'com.ywa'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '21'
    targetCompatibility = '21'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-orgjson:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.20.0'
}

//tasks.named('test') {
//  useJUnitPlatform()
//} (commented the tests to be able to be able to run at least the "gradle clean" and "gradle build" tasks
```

Literally everything. I tried looking for help everywhere, used the `liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.20.0'`, but nothing works.

Also, in case it's necessary, here is my liquibase.properties and application.properties files, as well as an image of how the project looks rn:

`liquibase.properties`

```
changeLogFile=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/dml-local-db
username=user
password=password
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
```

`application.properties`

```
#--Local host for devs--
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/dml-local-db
spring.datasource.username= user
spring.datasource.password= password
spring.liquibase.enabled= true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

# App Properties
dml.app.jwtSecret= mysecret
dml.app.jwtExpirationMs= 3600000
dml.app.jwtRefreshExpirationMs= 86400000

## For test
#dml.app.jwtExpirationMs= 60000
#dml.app.jwtRefreshExpirationMs= 120000
```

[image: Current state of the project]